# Euclidean norm of summation of scalar with vector

Tags: linear-algebra

in particular, where x is a d-dimensional vector and $x_i$ is a data point and $x_j$ is one of its neighbors:

$$\sum_{i}\left\| \sum_{j}{w_{ij}(\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{x}_j)} \right\|_{2}^{2} = \sum_{i} \sum_{jk}{w_{ij}w_{ik}(\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{x}_j)^{T}(\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{x}_k)}$$

Where does the $k$ come from?

I tried looking up some properties of norms but I couldn't wrap my head around it. Further, I couldn't understand how the norm works with sums and products of vectors and scalars.

I tried expanding the term to:
$$\sum_{i}\left\| \sum_{j}{w_{ij}(\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{x}_j)} \right\|_{2}^{2} = \sum_{i}\left\| {w_{i1}(\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{x}_1)+...+w_{i1}(\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{x}_{J})} \right\|_{2}^{2}$$
but this didn't seem to help.

Note: The whole thing comes from local linear embedding (LLE) but I don't think that its relevant for this questions

Comment: $\|v\|^2=v^tv$, so the last expression you wrote down expands to a sum involving all terms of the form $(x_i-x_j)^t(x_i-x_k)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thats exactly where my mental gap is as (for whatever reason) I can't "see" it. I would be really glad if someone could sort of spell it out for me so I can see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\left\| \sum_{j}{w_{ij}(\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{x}_j)} \right\|^{2} 
&= \left(\sum_{j}{w_{ij}(\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{x}_j)}\right)^T\left(\sum_{j}{w_{ij}(\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{x}_j)}\right)\tag1\\
&= \left(\sum_{j}{w_{ij}(\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{x}_j)}\right)^T\left(\sum_{k}{w_{ik}(\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{x}_k)}\right)\tag2\\
&=\sum_{j}\sum_{k} w_{ij}(\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{x}_j)^Tw_{ik}(\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{x}_k)\tag3\\
&=\sum_{jk}w_{ij}w_{ik}(\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{x}_j)^T(\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{x}_k)\tag4\end{align}$$

- (1) is just the definition of the norm.
- In (2), I changed the index of summation in the second factor from $j$ to $k$. Recall that the index of summation is a dummy variable. The expression does not actually depend on this variable. If you were to write it out term-by-term, nowhere would a $j$ or a $k$ occur. Thus it does not matter what we call this variable. It is just a matter of our own convenience. However, there is one rule about variables that we cannot ignore, even for dummy variables: Within a particular context, a variable can have only one meaning. Everywhere it occurs, it must have the same value. In (1) I have $j$ occurring as the index of summation for two different sums. This is okay because the context for each $j$ is limited to its own summation, and the other summation is outside of this. But in (3), that is going to change. So before that can happen, I need to switch one of the summations to use a different index.
- in (3) I use linearity of the transpose and the distributive law to move one of the summations inside the other, and then the distributive law again to move the other summation to the front as well. This is why I need different indices of summation, because now the $j$ and $k$ are used in the same context.
- Finally, the two summations are combined into a double summation (which just means the same thing) and the coefficients are pulled together.